# How to push signInWithCredential to Firebase, using 'expo-auth-session/providers/google'

Tags: react-native

The google sign in works fine, got the accessToken, but I don't see the credentials pushed into Firebase. the following is the code.

```
export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = React.useState();

    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
    const [request, response, promptAsync] = google.useAuthRequest({

        androidClientId: '***',
        iosClientId: '***',
        clientId : '***',

        scopes: ["profile", "email"],
        permissions: ["public_profile","email", "gender", "location"],

    });


    React.useEffect( ()=>{

            if(response?.type === "success"){

           const accessToken = response.authentication.accessToken;

           const idToken = response.authentication.accessToken;

            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken,accessToken);

            console.log(accessToken);

            signInWithCredential(auth,credential);

        }   
          //return Promise.reject();
    }, [response]);
```

here is the complete useAuth.js file

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import {View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity , StyleSheet} from "react-native";

import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";
import * as React from 'react';
import * as google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import {GoogleAuthProvider, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithCredential, signOut} from "@firebase/auth";
import {auth} from "../firebase";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = React.useState();

    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
    const [request, response, promptAsync] = google.useAuthRequest({

        androidClientId: '***',
        iosClientId: '***',
        clientId : '***',

        scopes: ["profile", "email"],
        permissions: ["public_profile","email", "gender", "location"],

    });


    React.useEffect( ()=>{

            if(response?.type === "success"){

           const accessToken = response.authentication.accessToken;

           const idToken = response.authentication.accessToken;

            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken,accessToken);

            console.log(accessToken);

            signInWithCredential(auth,credential);

        }   
          //return Promise.reject();
    }, [response]);

    return (

         <AuthContext.Provider value={{
        user : null,
       // signInWithGoogle,
        promptAsync,
            
    }}> 
    
    {children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    ); 
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex : 1, 
        backgroundColor : '#fff',
        alignItems : 'center',
        justifyContent : 'center',

    },
});

export default function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

here is the loginScreen.js file,

```
import React from "react";
import {View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";

const LoginScreen = () => {

    const {signInWithGoogle} = useAuth();

    const {showUserInfo} = useAuth();

    const {promptAsync} = useAuth();
    const {user} = useAuth();

    console.log(user);

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>
                Login to the app
            </Text> 
            
          {/*  <Button title = "Login" onPress={signInWithGoogle}/>   
               */}  

            <Button title = "Login" onPress={()=>{
                    promptAsync();
                }}/>    
        </View>
    )
}
export default LoginScreen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally get it working by changing "idToken" to "null" of the the credential line, as the following;

```
const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null,accessToken);
```

hope it helps, if someone maybe facing the same problem.

Comment: Dude this saved my life, I've been trying to figure out how to obtain both idToken and accessToken from ExpoAuthSession all day. Turns out I didnt need to. Thank you

Comment: omg life saver, thanks !
How tf is this not clearer in firebase docs...